# $cordovaFile.createDir not working, showing TypeError

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i am using $cordovaFile to create a directory in android platform. I used that code:

```
$cordovaFile.createDir("new_dir", true)
      .then(function (success) {
        alert(success);
      }, function (error) {
        alert(error);
});
```

But its showing `TypeError` on browser and device both.

Kindly suggest me how i can create directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I tried using the same code I got the following error: `{"code":5,"message":"ENCODING_ERR"}` and I was able to solve that error and your error by supplying a path as a parameter.

The `createDir` functions takes three parameters `createDir(path, directory, replace)`, that may be the reason why you are getting this error.

So if you change your code to the following, it should work:

```
$cordovaFile.createDir(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "new_dir", true)
  .then(function (success) {
    alert(success);
  }, function (error) {
    alert(error);
  });
```

Keep in mind that there are many different locations you can use to save data, you can find all the different available paths in the [documentation of the plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files).